# Very simple jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simply put, my `jQuery` is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery 101</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
<script src="/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
alert('hello world');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The included `jQuery` file is definitely in the filesystem and the `alert()` function is working, however this simple jQuery example is not working. This may be a rookie error, but I'm not really sure why.

- Using `JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final` for deployment
- Using `Google Chrome` for viewing

**EDIT:** I managed to fixed the original issue: it was due to the fact that i was not referencing the scripts correctly. as the 'scripts' folder is located at the root of the webapp, when i changed the reference to this:

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

(Note the two preceeding dots) It seemed to work fine!

Comment: Looks like your jquery did not load properly in the first case.. It may be in the file system.. Try this after your alert .. `console.log($)`

Comment: Local files need a specific protocol, `http://` or `https://`, or `file:///` if the browser allows use of local files. Chrome, I think, requires a switch, or flag, for `--allow-access-from-files`.

Comment: It does work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/YqYsx/

Comment: It's absolutely a file system problem. Your exact demo works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/esQxp/

Comment: Is this html file served through a web server or is simply a file in the local disk that you double click to load in the browser?

Comment: through the web server @PauloBu, the war is deployed with both files onto the AS. I'm going to try running it from an admin account to see what happens, although i'm currently at work and cannot work on personal things atm :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR You can use the online script source :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Works fine

Comment: this did work for me. i don't know why it's not detecting my server file though. strange.

Answer (score 1):

try to test the script location:

```
<script src="http://yourserver.com/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

make sure that http://yourserver.com/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js infact leads to jQuery.

Comment: Could it be due to the fact that i am not an admin account?